# Specifying an input ID in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Let's say my page has multiple forms all with unique IDs. But each of the inputs and their IDs are the same throughout the forms. Now if `#form02` is submitted, how do I grab that form's `#emailaddress` using jQuery?

I know how to grab `$("#emailaddress").val();` but this seems to be only representing one input and my not be from the form I'm submitting. Or is the only way to do this is to give every input a unique ID?

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique for the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make only the topmost forms have ids, since they truly are unique.  For all other elements, use classnames.  Then you can get `$("#form02 .emailaddress")`

Per the docs for [jQuery's id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

Comment: Actually, @matewka's first selector idea, `$('#form02 #emailadress')` would actually give you the results you want as well, but as the documentation says - don't rely on this.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, `id` must be unique for the **entire page**.
**Second**, you can specify selectors just like in CSS:

```
$('#form02 #emailadress')
```

The above code is of course incorrect, in relation to the first statement. I'd suggest something like this

```
<input class="emailadress" ...
```

and then

```
$('#form02 .emailadress')
```